# Replace text in status line flags

Tags: vimrc, statusline

How could I replace text in status line flags?

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%r%m
```

Is there a way to replace `[RO]` to `Read only`, and `[+]` to `Modified`?

Comment: I agree that vi.stackexchange is the better place to ask, anyway you should not crosspost.

Comment: @Ralf I assumed to wait for the first answer and then immediately remove duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional expressions when defining the statusline. Like:

```
set statusline+=%{&modified?\"Modified\":\"\"}
set statusline+=%{&readonly?\"Read\ Only\":\"\"}
```

See `:help 'statusline'` (it's a long text).

The `&modified` is the notation to access a option from Vim script. As `modified` and `readonly` are are boolean options, you can test them as shown above.

To check for a help file you would need:

```
set statusline+=%{&ft==\"help\"?\"HELP\ ME\":\"\"}
```

Here `ft` is short for the option `filetype`.

At some point you might be better off by moving all this stuff into a function to return the statusline. Like:

```
set statusline=%!MyStatuslineFunction()
```

The plugin [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) does it this way.

Comment: @Mass Does it realy influence the statusline? I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Ralf Hmm, I checked the help article, but there are no mentions of `&modified` or `&readonly`. Where I could find these "long words" for another flags, e.g. `h` flag and `w` flag?

Comment: At some point, I’d pull this out into a function and use a dictionary, if I really wanted to change lots of values

Comment: @johnc.j. see update

Comment: @Ralf you are right